# File targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with project's target platform 'x86'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create an installation from scratch using Visual Studio 2019 for a old project (it builds) Every time I try to build, I get the

> Error: WARNING: File ' something.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'.

I am able to use VS2019 to build the old project though.
how can I take to resolve this problem?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: x86 = 32-bit not 64-bit, x64 = 64-bit not 32-bit.  The two do not work together in one application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be targeting 64-bit (x64 / AMD64) platform for your project build, as one of your components - something.dll - is 64-bit.

To configure a project to target a 64-bit platform

On the menu bar, choose Build > Configuration Manager.

In the Active solution platform list, choose a 64-bit platform for the solution to target, and then choose the Close button.

More details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2022

Comment: I added a screenshot to my OP, it gives me the same error message.

Comment: What’s on the `active solution platform` drop down options?

Comment: the drop down has Win32, x64, Edit, and New. Under Edit I can only Remove, as for New, I can create either a new platform of either ARM or Itanium, copying settings from Win32 or x64. There is also a checkbox for creating a new solution platform.

Comment: If you set that drop down to x64, what happens?

Comment: How can you do this? For software project you can edit configurations, for setup project the option for adding AMD64 isn't available.

Comment: @JariTurkia what do you get if you go to `menu bar, choose Build > Configuration Manager`?

Choose your active configuration, select `New`, then in the `New platform` drop down you should see `ARM32`, `ARM64`, `x64`, `x86`. 

*x64 is AMD64*

Comment: @MikeIrving I can alter configurations for code project/projects as you suggest. The chosen deployment project platform is in the project properties `TargetPlatform` in a drop-down. Changing that from x86 into x64 makes depoyment build work.

Comment: Excellent. Compiling for x64 has solved the problem, as expected @JariTurkia

Comment: @MikeIrving Binary was AMD64 all the time. Compiling didn't solve the problem. Telling deployment project not to use x86 build results solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

- When building your setup package you need to target a specific target platform: x86, x64, or Itanium.
- Select your setup project in the Solution Explorer, then open the Properties Window (View > Properties Window)
- Change the TargetPlatform to match the Platform target you set for your WinForm application (see screenshot below).

Source
https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1548930